# Ajax is not working when page is loaded by typing url. but works fine if page is loaded by clicking on link on other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my `header.php` file I have many jQuery functions like change form on button click.

Everything is working fine, but two jQuery functions, that have ajax involved, do not work fine when I load the page by typing link in the browser. But they work fine when I load the page by clicking on the link on other page.

Here is my jquery code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#email_s').change(function(){
    var email = $('#email_s').val();
    if(email != '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/checkuser",
        method:"POST",
        data:{email:email},
        success:function(data){
          $('#emailseller_result').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('#username_s').change(function(){
    var username = $('#username_s').val();
    if(username != '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/checkusername",
        method:"POST",
        data:{username:username},
        success:function(data){
          $('#userseller_result').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please define *«do not work fine»* and *«work fine»*  in more details.

Comment: when i open the page by typing url in browser jquery did not work at all. but if i open the same page by clicking link on other page it works fine.

Comment: That just can be `echo base_url();` missing... The link click is probably handled in your site, to do something more than jus a normal link. I can't figure it out with the code you posted.